# Convert csv to json with django admin actions

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, django-admin

Register a csv in django-admin and through an action in django-admin to convert to json and store the value in a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField)

However, in action django-admin I'm getting this error and I can't convert it to json...

admin.py

```
(....)

def read_data_csv(path):
    with open(path, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        data = []
        for row in reader:
            data.append(dict(row))
        return data


def convert(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for extraction in queryset:
        csv_file_path = extraction.lawsuits
        read_data_csv(csv_file_path)
```

Error:

```
TypeError at /admin/core/extraction/
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FieldFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about `extraction.lawsuits` which is a FieldFile instance. Just pass `read_data_csv` function `csv_file_path.path` as argument. That should work.